# Unable to find code sign option in code for OSX Mountain LIon

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-gatekeeper

Trying to codesign an application for compatability with Gatekeeper introduced in OSX 10.8

Following the instructions in https://developer.apple.com/resources/developer-id/Developer-ID-Tutorial.pdf

- Create a Developer Account and waited for confirmation
- Created and exported developer certificates from Xcode 4.4
- Created a new OSX/Cocoa Application and set Product Name and Company
  Identifier field to give correct Bundle Identifier

Then on page 9 of the pdf the section **Code Signing with a Developer ID Certificate**  tells me to go to build settings, and search for “code signing” to show only code signing settings.

But I see no code signing options,

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your target in Xcode and search for "Code Signing Identity" (CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY), and put "Developer ID Application".

You can also manually sign an application in the Terminal:

```
codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application" MyApp.app
```

You can verify if your application is correctly signed:

```
codesign -vvv MyApp.app
```

Comment: Yes, found independently that selecting a target was the missing step, thanks.